# How to check for internet connectivity when device is connected to a network (wifi/3G) but there is no internet access in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, internet-connection, network-connection

I know there are packages like [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple and [Reachability.swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift), but using them you can only check if you are connected to a network such as 3G or wifi. You can not check if you have internet access through those connections. There may be no internet access due to exceeding quota or some other network problem. What can I do in such a case to check for internet access?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the request time out. Timeout you can set before calling the service. Implementation depends on the module/ library which you use for your project.